# How do I choose a domain name based on monthly searches for keywords?

Tags: seo, domains, google-search-console, google-search

Suppose I have 3 domain name phrases:

1. thisisfirst.com (competition is 11% and global monthly search is 151,000,000)
2. thisissecond.com (competition is 5% and global monthly search is 33,50,000)
3. thisisthird.com (competition is 1%, global monthly search is 49,500, local search is 3,600)

How can I decide which domain to use?

Answer (score 2):

Just thinking about SEO this is a very good question.  My personal opinion is that I would pick the third option, try and get 50% of those 49,000 a month and from that be able to build a platform where you get traffic not just because of your name, with links going into your site (perhaps using the first term's wording) you could become a competitor in those other levels.

Are we to assume those that the three choices all make good marketing sense if you ignore SEO, do they reflect the brand/product/site well and would humans find them all easy to type and remember?

If, for example the third option was just a really weird spelling of the first example with another word added to the start or end then there is a reason why so few people search for it each month.

Answer (score -1):

You can choose any domain whether it is relevant or not. But it must be easy for user to remember.

Comment: I've downvoted this because you haven't helped the questioner decide which domain to use.